# Passing html template in attribute - Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-template, angular-module

I have one component where I am trying to compile html template from an attribute. In this component I have an Input called htmlCompile that I want to fill with an attribute in the component selector. But when I did it and the project compiles, I get warnings.

My doubt is.. I am doing well or there is a better way to pass html from the selector.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'exampleComp',
    templateUrl: this.htmlCompile
})
```

And in the usage is:

```
<exampleComp  class="col-xs-8 col-sm-9" [htmlCompile]="./exampleComp.component.html"></exampleComp>
```

The warning result is:

WARNING in ./src/app/....../exampleComp.component.ts
495:18-43 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
    at CommonJsRequireContextDependency.getWarnings

Any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: What will you use in future - AOT or JIT?

Answer (score 0):

this is impossible the compiler need to know the template of component before it starts compilation. the compiler parses the template and convert it to plain javascript so there is no way to that.

Comment: There is a way and you need to use dynamic component creation.